# TextOverflow.visible not available (same code was ok on another computer)

Tags: dart, flutter

Have the following code:

```
Text(
    item,
    softWrap: true,
    overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
),
```

Worked fine on a computer. Pushed to github, checkout on another computer, I get:

> The getter 'visible' isn't defined for the class 'TextOverflow'.

Tried: Flutter upgrade, packages get, packages upgrade, flutter clean.

Nothing seems to work.

It's the same code, both machines are macs running the same version of the OS and everything else.

Both have the latest version of Android Studio, with the latest versions of the Flutter and Dart plugins.

I am stumped. :(

**edit**

Print screen of the "visible" field in TextOverflow:

[image]

Comment: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/TextOverflow-class.html
there is no visible , try TextOverflow.ellipsis

Comment: I edited my question to include a print screen of the field visible being available (under ellipsis) in TextOverflow.